# I want to convert a binary code to a grey code using 16-to-1 MUX

Tags: optimization, binary, logical-operators

The problem is that I didn't learned yet adders or VHDL (which a lot of people are telling me to use them) but all I have is 16-to-1 MUXs.

Should I link each MUX with the other from the select input? (Knowing that I have 4 inputs and 4 outputs obviously)

P.S: I am new to this kind of stuff and I am having a hard time to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Converting binary to Gray code is pretty easy.  In C it's just `gray = bin ^ (bin>>1)`.  You need on XOR gate for each bit except for the highest one.

There's a nice schematic over here: https://www.electrical4u.com/binary-to-gray-code-converter-and-grey-to-binary-code-converter/

You can make an XOR easily with a 4-to-1 MUX.  You can, of course, make one with a 16-to-1 MUX too, by tying two of the inputs to ground, but it's a big waste of gates.